# How to transfer context to a WebSocket session on reconnect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, websocket

I am working on a web application in C#, ASP.NET, and .NET framework 4.5 with the use of WebSockets.  In order to plan for scalability in the future, the application pool has the option for web gardens enabled to simulate multiple web servers on my single development machine.

The issue I am having is how to handle re-connects on the websocket side.  When a new websocket session is initially created, the client browser can indirectly lock records in a SQL database.  But when the connection is lost, my boss would like the browser to attempt to re-connect to the *same* instance of the websocket server session so it doesn't need to re-lock anything.

I don't know if something like this is possible because on re-connect the load balancer will "randomly" select which web server to handle the new connection.  I was thinking of some hack to work around this but it isn't very clean:

1. Client opens initial websocket connection on Server A and locks a record.
2. Client temporarily loses internet connection and the websocket closes.  (It is important to note that the server side will wait up to 60 seconds before it "disposes" itself; therefore, the SQL record will remain locked until the 60 seconds has elapsed).
3. Client internet connection is restored and reconnects to the website but this time on Server B.
4. Server B sees that this context was initially connected on Server A; therefore, transfers the session to Server A.
5. Server A checks the process id to see if it is running in the correct worker process (in the case of a web garden).
6. Server A has found the initial instance and handles the connection.

I tried Googling this question but it doesn't seem like a very common issue because I don't think most websocket web apps keep records locked for as long that my applications does (which is could be up to an hour).

Thanks in advance for all of your help!

**Update 3/15/2016**

I was hoping that the `Server.TransferRequest` would have been helpful however it doesn't seem to work for web sockets.  Would anyone know of a way to best transfer a websocket context from one process to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you might want to re-examine why you're locking records for a long time and requiring a client to come back to the same server every time.  That is not the usual type of high scale web architecture and perhaps you're just creating this need to reconnect to the identical server because of that requirement when maybe you should rethink how that is designed so that your application would work just fine no matter which host a user connects to.

That would certainly simplify scaling to large numbers of users and servers if you could remove that requirement.  You can always then implement local caching and semi-sticky connections later as a performance enhancement, but only after you release the requirement to 100% of the time connect to the same host.

If you're going to stick with that requirement to always connect to the same host, then you will ultimately need some sort of sticky load balancing.  There are a lot of different schemes.  Some are driven by the networking infrastructure in front of your server, some are driven by your server and some are even client driven.  They all have different tradeoffs.  Here's a brief run-down of some of the schemes:

1. **Hardware, networking load balancer.**  Here you have a fairly transparent mechanism by which a hardware load balancer (which is really just software running on a custom piece of hardware) sits in front of your web server farm and uses various techniques to make sure whatever server a given user is originally connected to it will get reconnected to on subsequent connections.  This can be based on various schemes (IP address, cookie value, etc...) as the key to identifying a particular user and it typically has a number of possible configurations for how it can work.
2. **Proxy load balancer.**  This is essentially an all software version of the hardware load balancer.  Here a proxy sits in front of your server farm and directs connections to a particular server based on some algorithm (IP address, cookie value, etc...).
3. **Server Redirect.**  Here an incoming connection is randomly assigned to a server.  Upon connection the server figures out where the connection is supposed to be connected to an returns a 302 redirect to the actual host causing the client to reconnect to the proper server.  This involves one less layer of infrastructure (no physical load balancers), but exposes the different server endpoints to the outside world which the first two options do not.
4. **Client Selection Algorithm.**  Here the client is given knowledge of the various server endpoints and is coded with an algorithm for consistently selecting one for this user.  It could be a hash of a userID that is then divided into the server bucket pool and the end result is that client ends up choosing a particular DNS name such as `cl003.myserver.com` which it then connects to.  This choice requires the least work server-side so can be simpler to implement, but it requires changing the client code in order to modify the algorithm.

For an article on sticky load balancing for Amazon Web Services to give you an idea on how one mechanism works, you can read this: [Elastic Load Balancing: Configure Sticky Sessions for Your Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html).

Here's another article on how the [nginx proxy is configured for sticky load balancing](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#nginx-configuration).

You can find lots of other articles with a Google search for "sticky load balancing".

A discussion of the pros/cons of the various schemes is the subject of a much longer discussion and some of it involves knowledge of more specific requirements and specific capabilities of your infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00!  Very good response.  I'll check out that article.  Now that I know what the industry term is for my situation hopefully I can find a solution.  I'll report back as soon as I can.

Comment: I just did some research on sticky sessions and the only thing that I can find for ASP.NET is to either use the ASP.NET Session State server or SQL to store the session state.  But the problem is that I cannot use the session state in this mode because it only stores simply data types (strings, integers, etc.) and the SQL record is being locked by an object.  I'll continue searching but it is beginning to look grim.

Comment: @vbguyny - Do you follow that 3 of the 4 types I outline are not dependent upon your specific server technology?

Comment: yes however from my research so far it looks like most of the solutions won't work in a web garden setting.  I am still looking though.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is possible to do with web gardens.  The closest this I could find would be to only have a single w3wp.exe process on the server and then employ one of the methods that you indicated above.

Comment: @vbguyny - It appears that web gardens do not have sticky sessions so you can't use the web garden for sticky load balancing.